# Некорректная проверка ввода C++

Tags: c++, ввод, проверка

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void repeat()
{
    char result;

    cin >> result;

    if (result == 'y' || result == 'Y')
        cout << "Povtor";
    else if (result == 'n' || result == 'N')
    {
        cout << "Vihod" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Enter Y or N" << endl << endl;
        repeat();
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Enter Y or N" << endl;
    repeat();
    
}
```

Проверка правильно работает с одним символом, но если ввести несколько, то проверка будет проходить по каждому из них, столько же раз повторно вызывая функцию, чем это вызвано и как можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читайте не `char`, а сразу строку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что происходит - ввод ожидал один символ, ввели много. и std::cin будет их по одному выдавать. Вы же ожидаете, что std::cin автоматически подрезает ввод по enter.

Что делать? читать всю строку сразу и проверять ее. Где то так

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void repeat()
{
     std::string line;
     std::getline(std::cin, line);

     // защита от пустой строки
    char result = line.empty()?'n':line[0];

    if (result == 'y' || result == 'Y')
        cout << "Povtor";
    else if (result == 'n' || result == 'N')
    {
        cout << "Vihod" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Enter Y or N" << endl << endl;
        repeat();
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << "Enter Y or N" << endl;
    repeat();
    
}
```

Я сделал минимальные изменения, но можно вообще отказаться от char переменной. Но это уже самостоятельно доводите до нужного состояния.

Comment: Благодарю!)
Правда когда вставил в основной код, всё сработало только после того как убрал строку:
 char result = line.empty()?'n':line[0];

До этого сразу завершало программу

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `strcmp()`. 0 значит равно.
`if(strcmp(result, 'y') == 0){ cout << "kod" << endl; }`

Comment: strcmp работает с указателем на char, но не с самим char